# Accessing another element from custom wxPanel wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Hello good people of stack overflow, I have run into a bit of a wall in creating an application. I am using custom wxPanels to display a few similar things.

What I'm having trouble doing is updating a master count when a counter in the panel is updated (the counters are wxSpinCtrl's) I can not, for the life of me, find a way to access the master spinctrl from any of the wxPanels.

I've tried passing a pointer to the master spinctrl, but when I try to access it from there I get a seg fault. I've tried setting up a custom event, but I don't know how to access the children of a wxPanel from the main panel. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this several ways, but the usual way is to use an event that is triggered when the user changes the spin control value.

You do not need a custom event, the provided wxSpinEvent is fine.

You do not need to access the spinctontrol, you can get the new value from the event

```
void OnSpin( wxSpinEvent& event )
{
  count = event.GetPosition();
}
```

Comment: I've tried doing that, however I can not find a way to access the wxSpinCtrl in the main frame. The rows are separate classes that are displayed in the original panel, not just multiple rows of the same items.

Comment: As I said, you do not need to access the control in the main frame.  The event has a method, shown, which gives you access to the new value of the control.